# Exsitence of extrema and boundedness of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:[0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function which converges for $t \rightarrow +\infty$.

What can you say about existence of extrema and boundedness of the function f?

Comment: What can you say about these matters? How about some thoughts, some ideas, some context, some work?

Answer (score -1):

If $\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{x \in [0,\infty)} \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} < \infty$ Holds it is bounded. If the image of $f$ is a compact set it attains its maximum and minimum

Comment: What does $|f(x)|/|x|$ have to do with it?